# Latex Table: understanding problem and caption problem

Tags: tables, longtabu

My code is not displaying anything related to table yet. Following is my code:

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen]{acmart}
\usepackage{listings}
\input{solidity-highlighting.tex}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes} 
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}


\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2020}
\acmYear{2020}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}


\begin{document}

\title{A Test of Latex}

\author{ Khan}
\email{Khan@edu}

\affiliation{}
  \institution{ University}


\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Trovato and Tobin, et al.}


\begin{abstract}
  Testing abstract
\end{abstract}


\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002978.10003022</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Testing and testingand privacy~ application security</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002944.10011122.10002945</concept_id>
<concept_desc>General and reference~Surveys and overviews</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Security and privacy~Software and application security}
\ccsdesc[500]{General and reference~Surveys and overviews}



\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Hello. \citet{1}, \citet{2}, \citet{3} %\cite{8} \cite{105} \cite{112} %\cite{48} \cite{87}.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Solidity] 
contract TestList1{

}
\end{lstlisting}
**begin{table}[]**
   \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l|ccccc|cccc|cc|ccc|ccc|ccc}

    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Testing Table for Classification.}
   \label{tab:classification}
 \vspace{-0.1in} 
\end{table}
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sourcefile-bib}


\end{document}
\endinput
```

I am getting following error message:

```
Package caption Error: \caption outside float.
main.tex, line 191
Too many }'s.
```

I can't understand following things:

```
begin{table}[]???Can't understand
\label{tab:classification}???Can't understand
\vspace{-0.1in} ???Can't understand
```

The image is:

[image: Caption and bracket error]

Comment: I have included solidity-highlighting.tex for solidity coding (link: https://github.com/s-tikhomirov/solidity-latex-highlighting/blob/master/solidity-highlighting.tex), I don’t know specifically the location of CCSXML and \ccsdesc but I have included following files in my project: ACM-Rference-Format.bbx,
ACM-Reference-Format.bst, ACM-Reference-Format.cbx, ACM-Reference-Format.dbx, acmart.cls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various things, like the file `solidity-highlighting.tex`, that you have not provided. Please make sure that your MWE is processible by others.

Anyway, your problem is that you said `begin{table}[]` instead of `\begin{table}[]`

Comment: Wrong answer. I already have "begin{table}[]" table in code. But I don't know what does it mean?

Comment: @user2994783, check again your code and answer. Answer clearly stated that error is missing backslash in `begin{table}`. Answer is very correct!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt answer. Sorry, I was not able to figure out my error.

Comment: But I have other questions also: begin{table}[]???Can't understand [ ].
\label{tab:classification}???Can't understand tab: Classification,
\vspace{-0.1in} ???Can't understand

Comment: @user2994783 Ask another question about these. If you ran your document with `\begin{table}[]` then these are not reported as errors. Do you mean that you don't understand what the `\label{...}` macro is for? Same for `\vspace`.